# NameError: name 'intents' is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is code:

```py
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands

file = open("config.json","r")
config = json.load(file)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intent=discord.Intents.default() )

@bot.command(name="ping")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} pong!")



bot.run(config['token'])
```

Here is an error:

```
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DISCORD_BOT\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(config['prefix'], intents=intents)
                                                 ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'intents' is not defined
```

Working in Visual Studio.

`bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intent=intents)` didn't help me.

Comment: The error and the code are unrelated. Did you save the file before running? Also, delete any `__pycache__` folders inside your `main.py` file's directory.

Comment: You defined it as `intent`, not `intents`. If you get NameErrors regarding variables, make sure you spelt it right.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple typing error instead of using the keyword argument `intents` you used `intent`, so the code should look like this:

```py
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands

file = open("config.json","r")
config = json.load(file)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=discord.Intents.default() )

@bot.command(name="ping")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} pong!")



bot.run(config['token'])
```

Hope this helps